# WSOD when selecting condition in Rules

Tags: 7, rules, wsod

In Drupal 7.63, I am trying to add a new rule, however I am being greeted with a WSOD. I am doing the following process...

1. Create a new Rule
2. Add condition
3. Select any condition from the drop down list

I then receive a WSOD with the following error in my browser console log:

[image]

Preceded by the warning:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I can see that other people have had this error in the past [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2634208), however I cannot see a solution to this. Similar to the referenced link I also have Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation installed (defaulted to jQuery 1.4.4).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the [advagg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) contrib module?

Comment: You can't be getting a WSOD and errors in the javascript console at the same time, and the JS errors be related to Drupal. A WSOD is literally a text string (or an empty string), no HTML (script tags), so that jQuery must be executed by a browser plugin or something else

Comment: @NoSssweat - Yes I am using the advagg module. I've left the JQuery version to the default 1.4.4

Comment: @Clive - There is no problem with anywhere else on the site, and there is a Drupal refrerence in the callstack of the javascript error. I've tried this is Firefox and Chrome and I get an error in both, with a whitescreen.

Comment: Sure, I was just letting you know that what you're looking at can't be a WSOD if that's the case. If the HTML source is there, and the JS etc is being loaded, but the page is completely white, then it's either a CSS/JS problem, or something wrong with your theme. But I doubt anyone would be able to identify what this is from here, you'd need access to the code to test it properly

Comment: @clive - sorry if I sounded a little agitated, this issue is a pain to resolve or find any info on. Looking at the callstack the Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.add_css throws an exception when attempting to access document.styleSheets[0] - of which there is none. This all seems to be invoked by the Rules UI with the callback for the ajax call being the "rules_ui_form_ajax_reload_form".

Comment: @clive - Is it possible to simply override the add_css command - just to check if document.styleSheets is undefined, therefore avoiding the exception?

Comment: @ernie Not necessary, I'm a dev too, I know how these things go ;) I'm almost certain you could monkey patch that function if you wanted to, but I'd imagine it's just masking a lower-level problem. Definitely worth a try, but I wouldn't be surprised to see a new error pop up in place of the old one once `add_css` doesn't do its thing any more. The other errors don't appear to be related to that one either, as they're related to jQuery UI trying to initialise. Have you considered the possibility of a virus or rogue browser extension? It kinda sounds like the `<body>` and/or `<head>` might be...

Comment: ...missing (which would make sense if you're seeing a blank page). I think you need to try to narrow down the cause of that (view the request in the browser, make the same GET or POST request to that URL with Postman or something else that doesn't run JS, and see if the response is the same, things like that). I'd love to offer more advice but it's a bit of a guessing game without being in front of it and being able to debug the code